# Android Bad Practices: Missing Google Play Services Updated Security Provider Remediation Effort(Hrs): 0.1

Tags: android, firebase

**I am getting the error on line no: 31 in the manifest file:**

<application

```
    android:name="com.assurant.inservice.ReassureApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">-----**line no 31**
```

//Inside network security config

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

**build.gradle file (app level)**

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-experimental-adapter:1.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.2"
```

//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation project(path: ':library')

}

**Build Gradle class level:**

dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

}
```

Comment: please guys help out for this question

Comment: You have not *asked* a question. What is your question? If your question is "why am I getting this error", what exactly is showing you that error? It does not look like something that shows up in Android Studio from ordinary Android app development, for example. Given the message and the affected line, you might reconsider why you have enabled cleartext traffic for all domains.

Comment: Sir my application is throwing security scan issues, and this issue is throwing on  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"  tools:targetApi="n"> line ..i did;t understand what is the problem . i have given my build file .issues was : Missing Google Play Services Updated Security Provider

Comment: What tool is "throwing security scan issues"? Have you talked to whoever created the tool that is "throwing security scan issues" to ask them what this error means and how to address it? And why do you have that particular network security configuration in the first place?

Comment: sir, they are scanning my code for security reasons and the tool is Fortify Software Security Center.they are generating pdf and mailed me they have given 600 issues and now this one issue is remaining. I have placed this network security config because in android 9 some API was not working then I got a solution

Comment: "the tool is Fortify Software Security Center" -- then you should talk to Fortify Software Security Center and ask them what their error message means. We cannot tell you what this Fortify Software Security Center error message means. All we can do is guess. Since enabling global cleartext traffic is one of the worst things a developer can do in terms of security, my guess is that this is what Fortify is complaining about. "because in android 9 some API was not working then I got a solution " -- then find a better solution.